# Minimum number of Hamiltonian Cycle(s)

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given a graph of size n (n vertices). State the minimum number of Hamiltonian Cycle(s) it can have
In a document I was looking for, it is

```
2^[(n−3)/2]
```

Is it true? How to prove it?

Comment: Can you define "size n"? What kind of graph is it? E.g. A tree on $n$ vertices have 0 Hamiltonian cycles. The complete graph on $n$ vertices has $n!$ cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [The minimum number of Hamilton cycles in a hamiltonian threshold graph of a prescribed order](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09250.pdf), *Theorem 6* stated:

> **Theorem 6.** The minimum number of Hamilton cycles in a hamiltonian threshold
> graph of order $n$ is $2^{\lfloor(n-3) / 2\rfloor}$ and this minimum number is attained uniquely by the graph $G_n$.

You can take a look at the proof there.